# How to assign all the '?' with object's data in JDBC template?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am new in spring boot.

I have created on method in spring boot, please see the below function:

```
public ArrayList<ShipmentDetailsVO> getShipmentStatus(
            ShipmentDetailsVO shpmntpert) {
        return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from SELECT_SEARCH_DETAILS(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",new ResultSetExtractor<ArrayList<ShipmentDetailsVO>>(){ 
            @Override  
               public ArrayList<ShipmentDetailsVO> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,  
                       DataAccessException {  
                shipmentDao = new ArrayList<ShipmentDetailsVO>();

                while(rs.next()) {
                     shipmentDetDaoObj =new ShipmentDetailsVO();

                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setContractNumber(rs.getString(1));
                     System.out.println("hello" + rs.getString(1));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setOrderNumber(rs.getString(2));
                     System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setShipmentNumber(rs.getString(3));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setShipmentControlNo(rs.getString(4));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setStatusCode(rs.getString(5));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setStatusDateStr(rs.getString(6));


                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setLastUpdatedtStr(rs.getString(7));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setResendFlag(false);
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setSourceSystem(rs.getString(8));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setDestinationSystem(rs.getString(9));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setRfid(rs.getString(10));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setUid(rs.getString(11));
                     shipmentDetDaoObj.setShipmentSeqId(rs.getString(12));

                     shipmentDao.add(shipmentDetDaoObj);
                                  }     
        return shipmentDao;
            }
        });
    }
```

I don't have any idea how to assign all the '?' with object's(shpmntpert) data. Can any one kindly help on the same.

Comment: Have you search a tutorial on this ?

Comment: Yes. In Tutorial it is mentioned , how bind with only one '?' with object[]. I need to bind all '?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [JdbcTemplate documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-)

You can find one of the `query` the signature

```
public <T> T query(String sql, Object[] args, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
        throws DataAccessException
```

With an explanation of the interesting parameters

> sql - SQL query to execute
>
> args - arguments to bind to the query

So you can see that the array is used to bing the values. That means that for a query like

```
select * from table where name = ? and weight= ?
```

you need to generate an array with those values in the correct order

```
new Object[]{name, weight}
```

---

An other signature show you that they provide some setter for PreparedStatement named [`PreparedStatementSetter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementSetter.html).

```
public <T> T query(String sql,
               PreparedStatementSetter pss,
               ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
        throws DataAccessException
```

Where the `PreparedStatementSetter` interface have only one methods to implements

```
void setValues(PreparedStatement ps)
```

That will let you set the values like you want fron this setter. You could pass the instance to an implementation of this interface or directly in the code like

```
final MyInstance m = new MyInstance();
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from table where name = ? and weight= ?", 
    new PreparedStatementSetter(){
        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps){
            ps.setString(1, m.getName);
            ps.setInt(2, m.getWeight);
        }
    }, myResultSetExtractor);
```

Note : This is a quick reading of the documentation knowing that I never used this API. But from what I have read, this should work just fine.